# Multiple instances of cmd.exe in one window?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I'm wondering. Can I open multiple instances of cmd.exe in *one* window.

I've been stuck because of this a couple of hours. Btw. I have *no* idea on how to do this nor if it's possible.

EDIT:
I am very sorry for not being informative enough. Sorry.
What I was looking is running two instances in one commandline.
This so I can listen to input with the command "choice" while not having to pause my "game". 
I am not looking for a browser-option with tabs. I'm looking for. If its possible running cmd.exe twice in one window.

Regards Kasper

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? Independent cmd.exe sessions in tabs, like in a browser? Why do you want to do this rather than just use separate windows? Why have you tagged your question [script] and [batch]?

Answer (score 0):

[Console 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) (or the fork [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console)) will let you have multiple instances in tabs in one window.

Answer (score 0):

In extension to Gerbal's answer, the following pieces of software (also) allow you to have tabbed instances of command lines in one single window:

- ConEmu (free, http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)
- CmdEr (free, http://bliker.github.io/cmder/)

Also, PowerCmd (free, http://www.powercmd.com/) lets you **tile** command windows, so you can also see progress and output at once (and it supports tabs also, if you don't like tiles).